# PHP set array of variables blank

Tags: php

I am using these variables in my site:

```
$_SESSION["domain.com"]["var1"]
$_SESSION["domain.com"]["var2"]
$_SESSION["domain.com"]["var3"]
```

and so on... how can i set all of these variables to a certain value at once?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. Just write a simple loop.

Comment: there are many different variables, is there a way to just do all at once?

Comment: *"there are many different variables"* - Define "many" and are the automatically incremented?

Comment: there could be 10,20,30 variables depending on which type of user logs in. it selects data from a database

Comment: When I was a kid, I learnt this 
"a = b = c = d = e = 0"

Comment: Then you're probably best using a session variable based on the user ID using a `WHERE` clause also.

Answer (score 3):

Write a simple nested loop:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as &$vars) {
    foreach ($vars as &$value) {
        $value = $default_value;
    }
}
```

I use reference variables so the loop can modify the elements directly, instead of having to assign to `$_SESSION[$domain][$variable]`.

Comment: I had thought of that also, but OP states - *"there could be 10,20,30 variables depending on which type of user logs in. it selects data from a database"* - Thought a `WHERE` clause would probably be best suited; *just a thought*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to set them all at the same time? Just set `['domain.com']` to an array.

```
$_SESSION['domain.com'] = array(
    'var1' => 'one',
    'var2' => 'two',
    'var3' => 'three',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to get you up and running:

```
$variables=[];
$setTo=1;
foreach($_SESSION['domain.com'] as $key=>$v){
    $variables[]=$key;
}
$prefix='$_SESSION["domain.com"]["';
$eval=$prefix.implode('"]='.$prefix,$variables).'"]='.$setTo.";";
eval($eval);
```

Perfect for production use.